# What is the best way to pass variables to my unittest instances?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've got test classes that inherit from unittest.TestCase. I load the classes multiple times like so:

```
tests = [TestClass1, TestClass2]
for test in tests:
    for var in array:
        # somehow indicate that this test should have the value of 'var'
        suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test))
```

Thing is, I want to pass the value of 'var' to each test, but I cannot use class variables because they are shared between every instance of the class, and I don't have access to the code that actually does the instantiation of the objects. What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: can you create another file which contains this share value of array?

Comment: I can edit the tests. What I meant by "I don't have access to the code that actually does the instantiation of the objects" is that the objects get created somewhere within the call to loadTestsFromTestCase(). If I rewrote the test loader, I could pass in the variable to init(), but that seems silly.

Answer (score 2):

I think that even if you don't have access to the class that implement the test cases, you can subclass them and overload the `setUp` method.

Comment: I can certainly add whatever I want to the `setUp` method. How will this help me pass in variables to the objects that get created?

Comment: @denaje My understanding is that you need each test case to have its own attributes (otherwise you would use class attribtes). Since `setUp` is executed before every test case, you can use a factory method to create the variables that you need and assign them to `self` for example.

Comment: The question is, how do I get the attributes into my test objects when the objects themselves are created by `loadTestsFromTestCase(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Rather than doing what you are trying there why dont you just do, say you have in class:

```
from my_tests.variables import my_array

class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUp():
         ....initializations...

     def tearDown():
         ....clean up after...

     def my_test_that_should_use_value_from_array(self):
         for value in my_array:
             test_stuff(value)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work, because I need each value to be in a separate test case rather than all in one test case. Also, I need to be able to specify what values to use dynamically instead of just iterating over a static array every time. If that's all I needed, I could just hardcode the array in my test class.

Answer (score 0):

---

UPDATE:

Since you need to:

1. feed some variable value to MyTestCase
2. run MyTestCase using this value
3. change value
4. If MyTestCase still running - use updated value.

Consider this:

1. keep values map in the file (.csv/.txt/.xml/etc.)
2. read values map from file in the `setUp()`
3. find value for your MyTestCase from values map using `TestCase.id()` method (as shown in the example below).
4. use it in the test cases.

---

`unittest` has handy `id()` [method](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id), which returns test case name in `filename.testclassname.methodname` format.

So you can use it like this:

```
import unittest


my_variables_map = { 
    'test_01': 'foo',
    'test_02': 'bar',
}


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        test_method_name = self.id()  # filename.testclassname.methodname
        test_method_name = test_method_name.split('.')[-1]  # method name

        self.variable_value = my_variables_map.get(test_method_name)
        self.error_message = 'No values found for "%s" method.' % test_method_name

    def test_01(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.variable_value is not None, self.error_message)

    def test_02(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.variable_value is not None, self.error_message)

    def test_03(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.variable_value is not None, self.error_message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This gives you:

```
$ python /tmp/ut.py 
..F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_03 (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ut.py", line 25, in test_03
    self.assertTrue(self.variable_value is not None, self.error_message)
AssertionError: No values found for "test_03" method.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
$
```

Comment: But I want to run each test case multiple times with different values. So, I run `test_01` with 'foo' and `test_01` with 'bar', and same for `test_02`, etc... With this solution, each test method would be bound to a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Data-Driven Tests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ddt) (DDT - not the pesticide) package helpful for this.

http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html